# Is there any way I can convert VARCHAR2 to SECONDS?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My output is like this

```
**Column1**              **Column2** 
20170123012057.555  20170123070616.314
```

I should get 20719 seconds if I minus the two columns

Comment: I see that the question is still opened. If you are satisfied with any of the answer, then `accept` it, so the question could be closed. Read [What to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Also close your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to a date and then take the difference:

```
select (to_date(substr(column2, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') -
        to_date(substr(column1, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
       ) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: I think miliseconds is not supported by to_date

Comment: @Potatooo . . . I think you are right.  The OP only wants seconds difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here I have given difference in `milliseconds` as well as in `seconds` which is rounded

```
select 
extract(day from (to_timestamp(column2,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
                 -to_timestamp(column1,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
                 )*86400*1000) / 1000 
    as diff_in_milliseconds  
,round(extract(day from (to_timestamp(column2,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')-
                         to_timestamp(column1,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
                         )*86400*1000) / 1000
     ) as diff_in_seconds
from 
(select
'20170123012057.555' as Column1,
'20170123070616.314' as Column2
 from dual)
```

Output

```
DIFF_IN_MILLISECONDS    DIFF_IN_SECONDS
20718,7590              20719
```

Comment: I'm getting ORA-01873.

Comment: are you running the exact query or did you change anything. Because this is working fine on my local and in rextester as well. Check http://rextester.com/YDYF44442

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT ROUND (seconds / 1000) seconds
  FROM (SELECT   EXTRACT (DAY FROM cal_col) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
               + EXTRACT (HOUR FROM cal_col) * 60 * 60 * 1000
               + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM cal_col) * 60 * 1000
               + ROUND (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM cal_col) * 1000)
                  seconds
          FROM (SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP ('20170123070616.314',
                                       'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
                       - TO_TIMESTAMP ('20170123012057.555',
                                       'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
                          cal_col
                  FROM DUAL))
```